# How to handle empty list for dynamic block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

This is regarding an Azure resource, app_service, but I think it’s a more general HCL question…

You can specify IP restrictions to an app_service using a dynamic block e.g.

```
locals {
  ip_addresses = [ "192.168.250.1" ]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-appserviceplan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "Database"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=some-server.mydomain.com;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  }

  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
    for_each = toset(local.ip_addresses)
    content {
      ip_address = each.value
    }
  }  
}
```

However, to remove the restrictions you need to explicit assign ip_restriction to the empty list, i.e.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  ...

  ip_restriction = []
}
```

What I don’t see is how to do this conditionally - if I make two resources and have those conditional my app_service will be created/destroyed whereas I need it updated in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the dynamic block does not support an empty list when using a conditional expression. Read more reference [here](https://medium.com/@business_99069/terraform-0-12-conditional-block-7d166e4abcbf).

After my validation, the conditional expression like `for_each = var.some_variable == "" ? [] : [1]` does not work when `var.some_variable` set to `null` but this could work seperately when `for_each = var.some_variable` and `var.some_variable` set to `null`.

So, in this case, as the answer from @rkm, you can use the `for` loop like this working sample for me.

```
variable "ip_restrictions" {

default = [
    #   {
    #   ip_address = "1.1.1.1/32"
    #   virtual_network_subnet_id = null
    #   subnet_id = null
    #   name = "aaa"
    #   priority = 110
    #   action = "Allow"
    # },

    # {
    #   ip_address = "2.2.2.2/32"
    #   virtual_network_subnet_id = null
    #   subnet_id = null
    #   name = "bbb"
    #   priority = 112
    #   action = "Allow"
    # },

]

}


resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "nn-example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {

  ip_restriction =  [

   for s in var.ip_restrictions :

   {

      ip_address = s.ip_address
      virtual_network_subnet_id = s.virtual_network_subnet_id
      subnet_id = s.subnet_id
      name = s.name
      priority = s.priority
      action = s.action

   }
  ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is special `terraform` syntax called [Attributes as Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/attr-as-blocks.html). Resource arguments defined using nested block syntax implicitly define [a fixed collection of objects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/attr-as-blocks.html#defining-a-fixed-object-collection-value) and thus in order to specify zero objects, we should explicitly set empty list. And these two forms cannot be mixed.

With that said, `terraform` supports an argument syntax too (even though they recommend using block syntax for simple cases for readability):

```
example = [
  for name in var.names: {
    foo = name
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone lands here looking for how to return a blank dynamic configuration block (instead of an input parameter like the OP), you can make the iteration list used by the for_each to be blank, and use conditionals in the content to set everything to null.

For example, if you have a dynamic inline_policy for AWS iam_role and you pass your inline json with a variable name policy_documents, you can first combine them into a single json document, then set a local variable to either a blank or what was passed in:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "combined_policy" {
  source_policy_documents = var.policy_documents
}

locals {
  policy_documents = length(var.policy_documents) == 0 ? [""] : [data.aws_iam_policy_document.combined_policy.json]
}
```

Now you can use local.policy_documents as the iterator for the dynamic block and the blank ensures the dynamic block will always generate something. To produce a blank inline_policy, you can test if the iterator is blank and set everything to null.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "default" {
  ... #(other parameters ommitted)

  dynamic "inline_policy" {
    for_each = local.policy_documents
    content {
      name   = length(inline_policy.value) == 0 ? null : "custom_inline_policy"
      policy = length(inline_policy.value) == 0 ? null : inline_policy.value
    }
  }
}
```

In the case where no inline policy is passed in, the dynamic block will generate a blank inline_policy {}:

```
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "default" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = {
                          + Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                      + Sid       = ""
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + id                    = (known after apply)

      + inline_policy {}
    }
```

I discovered how important a blank inline_policy is by accident when someone manually added an inline policy in the console, but the dynamic inline_policy did not notice it when I ran a terraform plan. If there was no inline_policy to start with, then the dynamic block never runs and so terraform doesn't check it. If you force the dynamic block to run even if the inline_policy is blank, terraform will ensure it is blank and delete the manually added inline policy. (Look [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#example-of-removing-inline-policies) and [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/attr-as-blocks#defining-a-fixed-object-collection-value) for terraform documentation and [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/default-to-null-on-dynamic-blocks/13458/6) for a good discussion at hashicorp about blank dyanamic blocks.)